# Can't install software using gnome-software on Fedora 29

Tags: linux, installation, fedora, gnome

I have recently installed Fedora 29  on HP ProBook 420 G2, previously Windows 7. 
The installation completed with no known issues, however now when I try to use gnome-software to install any software, the installation begins and always reaches 54% before showing the notification

> software_name cannot be installed as not supported

I can install the same software using the `dnf` command in terminal, but I would like, if possible, to be able to use gnome-software instead.

I have tried reinstalling gnome-software and packageKit, and also tried

```
sudo pkcon refresh force -c -1
```

But neither worked.
Ive tried googling around and can't find too much info (that worked) from the first few google pages. Any advice would be gratefully received.

Or is there a similar GUI application that performs the same as gnome-software?

Comment: Has Fedora been updated? If so, then try removing the gnome-software cache, https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/95444/gnome-software-not-working-on-fedora-24/

Comment: Thanks for your reply, yes first thing I did after installation was sudo dnf update, and I have tried removing gnome-software cache, not working

Comment: Thanks for reply, until there is a solution I will use dnfdragora, its visually a disaster but at least it works. Thanks in advance for any future answers